# Even moments of distribution given probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, moment-generating-functions

Given the probability density function $f(x)$, and the $[X] = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi\lambda}} $, how best should I  go about deducing the even moments of this distribution?

$f(x) = 4\sqrt{\frac{\lambda^3}\pi}$ $x^2$ $ (-\lambda x^2)$

I am trying to use integration by parts on $[X^2] = \int{{(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi\lambda}}})^2 4\sqrt{\frac{\lambda^3}\pi}x^2 (-\lambda x^2)dx}$

but am ultimately going wrong somewhere.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @JKnecht Ah sorry, X is defined for values greater than 0. Otherwise probability density function f(x) is 0.

Comment: Your density function is negative. And your formula for the second moment is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need for the probability density function

$f_X(x) \geq 0$ and for it to integrate to $1$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)\:\text{dx} = \int_{x \in D}{}f_X(x)\:\text{dx} = 1$$

Then for the moments

$$E[X^n] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^n f_X(x)\:\text{dx} = \int_{x \in D}{}x^nf_X(x)\:\text{dx} $$

and since you used the moment-generating function tag here is how you calculate your moments using that method instead of using the defintion above

$$  M_X(t) = E(e^{tX}) =
\begin{cases}
\sum_i e^{tx_i}p_X(x_i),  & \text{(discrete case)} \\
\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}f_X(x)\:\text{dx}, & \text{(continuous case)}
\end{cases}
$$

and the $n$th moment of $X$ is given by

$$E[X^n] = M_X^{(n)}(0) \:\:\:\:\:\:n = 1, 2...$$

$$M_X^{(n)}(0) = \frac{d^n}{dt^n} M_X(t) |_{t=0}$$